# jQuery live() ... have to click twice to activate links?

Tags: jquery, click, live

I have the following bit of code, simply:

```
$(function() {
  $('a.add-photos-link').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).colorbox({
      overlayClose: false,
      onComplete: function() {
        $('#add_photos').submit(function(e) {
          // more stuff to do
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

However, this only seems to work after single-clicking on the link TWICE. These links are dynamically added to the page (`a.add-photos-link`).

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it so it fires after the first single-click?

Comment: Where is your JavaScript located on the page? Is it executed after the DOM tree is built?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current code only creates a colorbox for the link. It does not open the colorbox, which is why you need to click the link twice: once to create it and again to open it.

You can use the `open` option ([as documented](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)) when creating the colorbox to open it immediately, like so:

```
$(this).colorbox({
  open: true,
  overlayClose: false,
  onComplete: function() {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: I have a similar issue.  I have an image on a page and I've added an onclick event to the image.  I've specified open: true but it still needs two clicks.

Comment: @MarcWilson Create a new question with your details.

Comment: I found it- jQuery has a new version released, where they've removed the "live" function - there's a new version of colorbox to go with the latest jQuery.

Comment: 3 years later this answer is still saving people time.